# Execute Function when a State Variable Changes inside of a useEffect() Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so I am trying to create a graph visualization front-end using [Antv's](https://g6.antv.vision/en/docs/manual/getting-started) G6 and React. I have this useState() variable and function as shown below:

```
const [hideNode, sethideNode] = useState("");
const hideN = () => {
    const node = graph.findById(hideNode);
    node.hide();
  };
```

The function is in charge of hiding the selected node. However, the problem with running this function as it is, is that it will raise the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'findById')` because `graph` is assigned inside of the useEffect() hook, as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!graph) {
      graph = new G6.Graph();
      graph.data(data);
      graph.render();
      hideN();
    }
  }, []);
```

It only works as intended if I call the function `hideN()` inside of the useEffect() hook, otherwise outside of the useEffect() if I `console.log(graph)` the result would be undefined.

So I wanted to ask, is there a way I could have this function run when the state changes while inside of the useEffect(), or is there a better way to go about this. I'm sorry I am super new to React so still learning the best way to go about doing something. I'd appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Full code:

```js
import G6 from "@antv/g6";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { data } from "./Data";
import { NodeContextMenu } from "./NodeContextMenu";

const maxWidth = 1300;
const maxHeight = 600;

export default function G1() {
  let graph = null;
  const ref = useRef(null);

  //Hide Node State
  const [hideNode, sethideNode] = useState("");
  
  const hideN = () => {
    const node = graph.findById(hideNode);
    node.hide();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!graph) {
      graph = new G6.Graph(cfg);
      graph.data(data);
      graph.render();
      hideN();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref}>
        {showNodeContextMenu && (
          <NodeContextMenu
            x={nodeContextMenuX}
            y={nodeContextMenuY}
            node={nodeInfo}
            setShowNodeContextMenu={setShowNodeContextMenu}
            sethideNode={sethideNode}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export { G1 };
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can just use a second `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `hodeNode` that calls `hideN`? Where is `graph` declared? Can you share a more complete code example?

Comment: Why not pass graph as an argument to `hideN`?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the post to include the full code. Took out any parts that I thought were unnecessary to the problem. I hope this helps

Comment: Well, `let graph = null;` happens every render cycle. Do you want the `graph` value to persist?

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah. I want it to persist.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava yeah it works when called within the useEffect(), which is why I was wondering is there a way that I could execute the function within useEffect(), but whenever the state "hideNode" changes. Because if you tried it outside of the useEffect(), it won't work. So I can't use a separate useEffect() for this function either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `graph` in a React ref so it persists through rerenders. In `hideN` use an Optional Chaining operator on `graphRef.current` to call the `findById` function.

Add `hideNode` state as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook and move the `hideN` call out of the conditional block that is only instantiating a `graph` value to store in the ref.

```
const graphRef = useRef(null);
const ref = useRef(null);

//Hide Node State
const [hideNode, sethideNode] = useState("");

const hideN = () => {
  const node = graphRef.current?.findById(hideNode);
  node.hide();
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (!graphRef.current) {
    graphRef.current = new G6.Graph(cfg);
    graphRef.current.data(data);
    graphRef.current.render();
  }
  hideN();
}, [hideNode]);
```